# import React from 'react' SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module

Tags: javascript, reactjs

hola buenas tengo el siguiente problema, el cual me dice que mi error esta en el import, pero al buscarlos no logro encontrar solucion.
este es mi codigo:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: qué versión de node y npm tienes? Sería bueno que mostraras desde donde estas importanto el módulo que mostaraste.

Comment: @Japsz la versión de node es v12.13.1. la del npm la mas actual y el modulo no lo estoy exportando

Answer (score 0):

Estoy con el mismo error parece ser provocado porque node no soporta ES6 por default. La solución mas común parece ser agregar "type": "module" al package.json mas cercano al archivo. Otra opción es agregar la extensión .mjs al archivo. A mi no me sirve ninguna de las dos opciones. En mi proyecto estoy usando create-react-app no se si es mejor idea configurar uno mismo react para proyectos mas grandes. Lo que no entiendo es porque el error salta en un archivo que estaba bien hace poco y que no he tocado.